# uiview to Uiview switch

Tags: iphone, uiview, switch-statement

I have a uiview class and i want to switch to other uiview class but without using addsubview 
is there any other way to do that except the one (addSubView)

Comment: how is your view created? which object "owns" the view (which object created it, i.e.: called `[[MyView alloc] init]`.

Comment: the owner is a uiviewcontroller class

Comment: Include your code and what you are trying to do based on an event. What have you tried? What was the result? Why were the results not to your liking? Your question does not provide enough context. What do you want the user to be able to do with the new view? Will you need the old view? Spend some time reviewing the UIViewController Class Reference documentation and ViewController Programming Guide for iPhone OS.

Comment: i have a uiviewcontroller class that has a nib and i am using some other class as its uiview by changing the UIVIEW option to "otherView" class in interface builder.
The result was ok it had a navigation controller and beneath it the "otherView"
the "otherview" deals with touches  
when i do addsubview("anotherView") on the "otherView" the touches thing is also enabled there. 
The "AnotherView" contains the text fields nothing else but as I press the backbutton from the "AnotherView" it pops out as it is supposed to do but i want it to switch to "otherview".

Comment: in simple words on back button action it shouldnt pop instead it should remove itself from superview

Comment: I take it that otherView is not visible after pressing the back button? addSubview places anotherView in front of otherView. I think you really want to use presentModalViewController:animated instead. You will need to create AnotherViewController toload anotherView and handle the textField events.

Answer (score 1):

If you have UIViewControllers for the corresponding UIViews, and have a UINavigationController to handle your view flow, you can use pushViewController message at the mentioned navigation controller.

Comment: yes i know that but i dont have any uiviewcontroller.... i just have uiview and i want it to  switch to other uiview but without using addSubview....

Comment: You do "i have a uiviewcontroller class that has a nib" and then you don't. Which is it? You will have to post your code.

Comment: dear falconcreek i have done something similar as u r guiding and i am done with my assignment, but; what actually i was trying to acquire was, is there any other way to switch to some UIVIEW from and UIVIEW without using addSubview....

Answer (score 0):

Since you have a navigation controller you can use `pushViewController:animated` to add `anotherViewController` to the navigation stack. You can also use `presentModalViewController:animated`. The section on Navigation Controllers in [View Controller Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/NavigationControllers/NavigationControllers.html) explains this very well.